# =QUERY syntax when working with data submitted via Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

The Query below 'works' on a line by line basis (when manually filled down), but it does not 'autofill' down when new data is added to the 'responses sheet'. The data being added to the 'responses sheet' comes from a Google form.

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:K; CONCATENATE("SELECT B, C WHERE A = ", responses!B1), 0)
```

**Question**
**One** - How do I adjust this Query so it will 'autofill' down when new data is added to the 'responses sheet' by a Google form?

If this is not possible, any suggestions?

[Here is a link to the Google Spreadsheet I'm working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNVNg1xSJ6-dGpvdFJGMmpuWExWeUE2SWhFQ21Wb3c&usp=sharing)

Thank you for your time and assistance,
Todd
High School Teacher

Comment: are you aware that you may have exposed personal data (names and email addresses of teachers) to public? or are they all made up for the example? (they do not seem to be)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [VLOOKUP applied as an array formula](http://productforums.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/docs/multivalue%2420parallel/docs/36A0epDlIdE/qnywZst0DioJ). This will auto-populate down the column as forms are submitted. So in row 2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B;Sheet2!A2:C;SIGN(ROW(B2:B))*{2,3};0)))`

or you can enter this in row 1, which will also populate headers, and is slightly more watertight when rows are inserted/deleted in certain situations:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1;{"First Name","Last Name"};IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B;Sheet2!A2:C;SIGN(ROW(B:B))*{2,3};0))))`

Answer (score 0):

One way you can get around this is by using [Google App Script (GAS)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

What is possible is to setup an onEdit function that will add the formula to the required cell when new data is added.

Using a very quick bit of code (below). This will apply your formula when the spreadsheet is updated.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("responses");
  var lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
  var studentID = ws.getRange(lastRow, 4).setFormula('=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:K; CONCATENATE("SELECT B, C WHERE A = ", responses!B'+lastRow+'), 0)');
}
```

I've copied your spreadsheet and set it up here -> [LINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An1-zUNFyMVLdDhqcHc0ZG1IdFpmSHpwSHp5alZQa0E&usp=sharing) You can test it by simply copying a new student ID into the B column and see that the student information is pulled from the second sheet.

Comment: vletech, THANK YOU! This solution does work, but it looks like the spreadsheet only 'updates' with the query data once the page is 'reloaded'. I tried going into the script editor and the page updated, but only the 'last' row. If the document has been updated by 3 new form submissions, only the last one (most recent) was updated with the =QUERY. Any suggestions to 1) automate it and 2) have it update all edits, not just the last edit? THANKS!

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't realise there would be multiple entries in one hit. Ok just quickly thinking, another way around it would be to iterate over all of the rows in the spreadsheet (when it changes) and if there isn't a formula in that cell then add it. As for not updating automatically, I got the function wrong it's not onEdit, it should be onChange. My Apologies.