# including a conditional statement in a =QUERY function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I add a conditional statement (similar to an 'if elseif' in .php) to the query listed below so that it will return columns D and E from Sheet2 if column C in the responses sheet == 1st, or columns F and G from Sheet2 if column C in the responses sheet == 2nd? It must still only return column data from the appropriate row (based on the query).

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A$1:K; CONCATENATE("SELECT B, C WHERE A = ", responses!B1), 0)
```

I looked into IF(OR), but I don't believe that will work because final project will have more than two possibilities (there will actually be eight, 1st through 8th class period).

[Here is a link to the Google Spreadsheet I'm working with](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhNVNg1xSJ6-dGpvdFJGMmpuWExWeUE2SWhFQ21Wb3c&usp=sharing)

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time and assistance,
Todd
High School Teacher

Comment: I agree with +Zig Mandel that this doesn't lend itself to QUERY. Before devising a solution, would my answer in your other question be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937012/query-syntax-when-working-with-data-submitted-via-google-form ?

Answer (score 1):

That cant be done with query. All rows must select the same columns.
Use a formula post-query (like an arrayformula)